# SES send email example for go giving "Process exited before completing request" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using this example from the AWS Docs:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/go/example_code/ses/ses_send_email.go

When I run the code in Lambda, it sends the email but says there is an error  "Process exited before completing request."

Comment: You used the exact code as in the link? What are your lambda configurations? How much memory/time do you see your function take in the metrics?

Comment: All I did was change the sender, recipient, and region config in the code. I haven't added any lambda configs. Memory Size: 128 MB and Max Memory Used: 27 MB. Duration: 1895.16 ms